# How to set authenticated user to serializer?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I created simple CreateAPIView using django rest framework.

```
class CreatePostAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'

class Post(models.Model):
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = False)
    spot    = models.ForeignKey(Spot, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = False)
    comment = models.TextField(null = True, blank =  False)
```

Model Spot has three fields

- user
- spot
- comment

From client, spot and comment are sent using http POST request param as from of JSON.

However user does not come with http POST request param but I need to get user from django's authenticated user(like request.user).  I know I can get user from request.user but how can I set the user to the serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the [**`perform_create(...)`**--(DRF doc)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#associating-snippets-with-users) method of **`CreatePostAPIView`** class and set **`user`** in [**`read_only_fields`**--(DRF doc)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields) in **`PostSerializer`** class

```
# views.py
class CreatePostAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)


# serializers.py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('user',)
```